# Accept username that is ecrypted by hash in the database

Tags: php, laravel, hash, passwords

When I'm creating a user, the username and password saves in a hash. Now I want my username and password when log in, can be read by the system. I am using Laravel

Below is my code for user controller

```
public function postSignin() {
        if (Auth::attempt(array('username'=>Input::get('username'), 'password'=>Input::get('password')))) {
            return Redirect::to('admin/dashboard')->with('message', 'You are now logged in!');
        } else {
            return Redirect::to('users/login')
             ->with('message', 'Your username/password combination was incorrect')
             ->withInput();
            }
        }
```

Comment: As far as i know, bcrypt is using one way hashing algorithm. So, as a short answer we can not produce username/password from hash.

Comment: The username should be stored in plain text and the password is what is hashed. Don't hash them both together. You should never be able to read the password in plain text and hashing is one-way.

Comment: Hi Mike. our software quality assurance request that username in log in should be case sensitive so I decide to encrypt username also

Comment: what does 'case sensitive' have to do with then encypting it?

Comment: Do you have any idea for log in that username is case sensitive. for example, if my username is all caps, then when I log in, the system can only accept my username in a capital letters.

Comment: in php `'dog'!='Dog'` http://codepad.viper-7.com/RpTEpA

Comment: Please fix your title spelling: when you write _ecrypted_, do you mean "decrypted" or "encrypted"?

Answer (score 1):

Case sensitivity does not require hashing.  You use a non _CI encoding in the database table. CI stands for case insensitive.

Assuming that you still want to hash the username, you would just need to hash the user input (username), in the same manner it is stored in the database, before passing it to the authentication script.